# Guard Giving "uninitialized constant Listen::Turnstile (NameError)" Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, guard

I'm having this error while trying to run the command:

```
guard
```

This is an app I've been developing for a while now before trying to install guard...

I'm following the instructions from Ryan Bates' tutorial on guard:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/264-guard

Here's my Gem file.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.14'
gem 'rake'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby'
gem 'devise'
gem 'rails_admin'
gem 'jbuilder'
gem 'gon'
gem 'dynamic_form'
gem 'therubyracer', :require => 'v8'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete'
gem 'roo'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.4'
  gem 'coffee-script', '~> 2.2.0'
  gem 'uglifier', '~> 1.2.3'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'bullet'
  gem 'rvm-capistrano'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.10.0'
  gem 'awesome_print'
  gem 'wirble'
  gem 'thin'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'rb-fsevent', :require => false if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /darwin/i  
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'spork', '~> 1.0rc'
end
```

Here's the full error:

```
app3 git:(write-tests) ✗ guard
    /Users/Nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/guard-1.4.0/lib/guard.rb:47:in `setup': uninitialized constant Listen::Turnstile (NameError)
        from /Users/Nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/guard-1.4.0/lib/guard.rb:155:in `start'
        from /Users/Nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/guard-1.4.0/lib/guard/cli.rb:104:in `start'
        from /Users/Nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from /Users/Nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_command'
        from /Users/Nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor.rb:363:in `dispatch'
        from /Users/Nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/base.rb:439:in `start'
        from /Users/Nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/guard-1.4.0/bin/guard:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/Nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/guard:23:in `load'
        from /Users/Nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/guard:23:in `<main>'
        from /Users/Nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
        from /Users/Nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had a similar problem with my rails 3.2.13 app.

The confusing part was that I did not have `gem 'guard'` in my Gemfile, but the gem was obviously a dependency of the following:

```
gem 'guard-rspec'
gem 'guard-livereload'
gem 'guard-cucumber'
```

everything worked until a recent `bundle update`, which brought in a much newer version of `listen`, one of `guard`'s dependencies, while `guard` itself was held back (not sure why). So the error you saw was `guard` trying to invoke a class that no longer exists in `listen`.

The problem was solved by explicitly adding the current version of `guard` to `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'guard', '>=2.1.0'
```

and of course re-bundling.

Comment: I added that specific version of guard and also added "guard-livereload". That's what did the trick. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Invoking "bundle" does not work for me. I've run "bundle update guard"  command explicity

Answer (score 13):

You don't have `gem "guard"` in your gem file.

I was getting the same error.

One of the plugins I had included, *guard-bundler*, was locking the guard version at 1.4.0, while the latest version of guard is 2.0.5. Removing that plugin fixed the error. Don't forget to remove the guard-bundler code from your guard file.

Im guessing that your guard gem is installed as a system gem. Put it in your gem file and run it with `bundle exec`.

There is also a dependency conflict between guard and better_errors on coderay. I pinned it at 1.0.5 to get them both installed. I haven't tested any functionality related to coderay to see if that version causes problems for better_errors.

`gem 'coderay', '~> 1.0.5'`

Comment: Updating from guard 1.4.0 to guard 2.0.5 was the trick for me.